# Filter Neo4j nodes that have no relationship with a certain node

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, cypher, neo4j.rb

I want to find all Foos that are not yet associated with my Bar.
I use neo4j.rb (4.1.2) and Rails (4.2). The code I use now, that produces the right output but feels unoptimal is:

```
@foos = Foo.all.find_all do |foo|
  foo.bars.rels_to(current_bar).count == 0
end
```

Is there a better way of doing this with Cypher?

Comment: Cyphersam's answer is good. You should upgrade to Neo4j.rb 4.1.2!

Comment: Upgraded neo4j.rb and updated the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one way to do this in Cypher. I assume you are only interested in direct relationships, and that `Bar` nodes are identified by an `id` property.

```
MATCH (b:Bar), (f:Foo)
WHERE b.id = 123 AND NOT (b)--(f)
RETURN b, COLLECT(f);
```

Comment: In Neo4j.rb, that'd be `current_bar.query_as(:b).match('f:Foo').where('NOT (b)--(f)').pluck(:b, 'collect(f)')`

Comment: Thank you @cybersam!

I had to do change the neo4j.rb version to `current_bar.query_as(:b).match('(f:Foo)').where('NOT (b)--(f)').pluck( 'collect(f)').first` to make it to work (missing ( and ) around f:Foo) and act like my old ruby code. For anyone who reads this. Thank you @subvertallchris!